# How to connect to HANA Database from AWS Lambda Python

Tags: python, aws-lambda, hana

I want to connect HANA Database from AWS Lambda Python and perform CRUD operations through queries. Please help me with this.
I have below details of the HANA database and can get the required details.

HANA HOST Name,
user name,
password,
database name,
port number,

Comment: I would go to the SAP HANA documentation or forum to see if there is a public API to do the crud operations you want. If there is, then it should be relatively easy to implement in a Lambda function in whatever language you prefer.